# Photo downloads from Box using lower than original resolution

Tags: box-api

Is it possible to download photos from Box folders in lower than original resolution using Box API v1 ? I know that normal and larger thumbnail versions of photos stored in Box can be downloaded. But is there any option to download photos with larger than thumbnails and lower than original resolution ? Downloading full resolution photos over 3G in mobile apps kills user experience.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I am using thumbnail (larger_thumbnail version in ipad) versions of photos in photo thumbnail view. Both thumbnail and larger_thumbnail URLs are available in get_account_tree and get_file_info API calls. These thumbnails are quick to download as well. However, I am downloading original photo using download API and then downsizing the photo to lower resolution in order to display the photo on device. This is where my problem is. To show a Box photo in photo view requires the app to download full resolution which takes long time particularly over 3G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than using thumbnails, there currently isn't a way to do this in the v1 API.